# glDrawArrays with buffer not working in JOGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

I was wondering whether someone can help me find out why my JOGL code does not show a triangle. There are no exceptions for some reason. Am I missing something?

```
    IntBuffer vacantNameBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(3);
    gl.glGenBuffers(1, vacantNameBuffer);
        int vertexBufferName = vacantNameBuffer.get();
    float[] triangleArray = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    FloatBuffer triangleVertexBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(triangleArray);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vacantNameBuffer.get());
    gl.glBufferData(
            GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            triangleVertexBuffer.capacity() * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT, 
            triangleVertexBuffer, 
            GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vacantNameBuffer.get());
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vacantNameBuffer.get());
    gl.glFlush();
```

Comment: Rather use direct NIO buffers created by com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer() instead of passing indirect buffers to JOGL methods. Do something similar for the float buffer, create it and call put() to fill it. Take care of the position as Reto Koradi wrote, he's right. When you use indirect buffers, JOGL has to make the conversion itself and in the future we'll probably only accept direct NIO buffers for purely OpenGL methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glEnableVertexAttribArray` expects the attribute location (the number you set as first parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer`) so you should change it to:

```
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my code, but for some reason, the triangle is still not showing

Comment: call gl.glGetError between openGL calls, and see where it starts returning something other than 0

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the IntBuffer here, but I changed the FloatBuffer like you advised. I tried the demo, and for some reason it works perfectly there, even though that part of my code looks the same. So I'm implementing a shader program to see if that helps. Thanks for the link to the demo

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in @ratchet_freak's answer, the arguments to `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glDisableVertexAttribArray()` need to be changed to pass the location of the attribute:

```
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
...
gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Beyond that, you have some problems in how you use your buffer objects. You have these types of calls multiple times:

```
vacantNameBuffer.get()
```

`get()` is the relative get method, which gets the value at the current buffer position, and then advances the position. So without resetting the buffer position, it will only give you the first value in the buffer the first time you make this call.

You already have a statement that gets the first value, and stores it in a variable:

```
int vertexBufferName = vacantNameBuffer.get();
```

All you need to do is use this value in the rest of the code, instead of calling `get()` again. So change this call:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vacantNameBuffer.get());
```

to this:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferName);
```

Another option would be to use `get(0)`, which gives you the value at an absolute position.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed 2 things according to what you told me. Unfortunately, the triangle is still not showing. I tried to use glError() as recommended but it outputs 0. It's really tough to debug without access to the methods or classes in JOGL. Are there anything else that I need to enable to use these methods?